# IIS Rewrite URL not appending StringQuery

Tags: iis, rewrite, querystring

I'm trying to rewrite my URL

FROM `https://localhost/details.html?page=2`

TO `https://localhost/license`

When I use *Redirect*, it works perfectly when I request the URL `https://localhost/license`, but the URL changes to `https://localhost/details.html?page=2`.

When I use *Rewrite*, the URL remains `https://localhost/license`, but the "redirecting" goes to `details.html` (static html) without parameter `page=2` (dynamically generated), even when I set `appendQueryString` to TRUE.

Redirect code (Working):

```
   <rewriteMap name="StaticRewrites">
            <add key="/license" value="/details.html?page=2" />
        </rewriteMap>
    </rewriteMaps>

    <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect Rule">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                <add input="{StaticRewrites:{URL}}" pattern="(.+)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
    </rules>
```

Rewrite code (Not Working):

```
   <rewriteMap name="StaticRewrites">
            <add key="/license" value="/details.html?page=2" />
        </rewriteMap>
    </rewriteMaps>

    <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect Rule">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                <add input="{StaticRewrites:{URL}}" pattern="(.+)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
    </rules>
```

Does anyone knows how can I configure *Rewrite* method to keep the URL `https://localhost/license` but to show the dynamic page `https://localhost/details.html?page=2`?